# Use of undeclared type or module near_blockchain

Tags: nearprotocol

I am getting the following error when trying to compile NEAR smart contracts, but only when compiling to wasm target

````
   Compiling nep9000 v0.1.0 (/Users/mikkoohtamaa/code/advanced-fungible-token/contract)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `near_blockchain`
   --> src/token.rs:144:1
    |
144 | #[near_bindgen]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `near_blockchain```
````

Normal `cargo build` is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to declare `#[near_bindgen]` on both `struct` and `impl` of the contract, `impl` only is not enough.

```rust
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Token {
   ...
}


#[near_bindgen]
impl Token {

   ...
}
```

Comment: Though not sure why I get this error only on wasm target.

Answer (score 3):

If you come across this error while breaking out your Rust smart contract into separate files, please use `use crate::*;` instead of what your IDE might suggest.

For instance, let's say we have this file structure in our project:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│  ├── my_mod.rs.     ⟵ here is the module file
│  └── lib.rs
└── build-and-test.sh
```

When you add a new file like `my_mod.rs`, you'll want to make sure `lib.rs` has:

```rust
mod my_mod;
```

Inside of `my_mod.rs` you might have your IDE suggest this:

```rust
use crate::Contract;
```

which should be replaced with:

```rust
use crate::*;
```